# Wrapping resolved instances - Unity Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

If I have the following code

```cs
[Serializable]
public abstract class ValidatedCommandArgs
{
}

public interface IValidatedCommand<T>
    where T : ValidatedCommandArgs
{
    IEnumerable<ValidationError> Execute(T args);
}
```

Now a simple implementation

```cs
public class CreateClientArgs : ValidatedCommandArgs
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CreateClientCommand : IValidatedCommand<CreateClientArgs>
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationError> Execute(CreateClientArgs args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then register the command handler

```cs
container.RegisterType<IValidatedCommand<CreateClientArgs>>, CreateClientCommand>();
```

Now what I want to be able to do is to wrap every resolution of IValidatedCommand so that I can essentially do this

```cs
public class LoggedCommandHandler<T> : IValidatedCommand<T>
    where T : ValidatedCommandArgs
{
    readonly IValidatedCommand<T> Inner;

    public LoggedCommandHandler(IValidatedCommand<T> inner)
    {
        this.Inner = inner;
    }

    IEnumerable<ValidationError> IValidatedCommand<T>.Execute(T args)
    {
        //Serialize ARGS
        //Save Inner.GetType().ClassName + the serialized args to the DB
        return Inner.Execute(args);
    }
}
```

Then whenever I resolve (for example) `IValidatedCommand<CreateClientArgs>` I would actually get an instance of `LoggedCommandHandler<CreateClientArgs>` which is resolved with `inner = CreateClientCommand`

Sorry for being so verbose, but I don't recall what the technique is called.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting edit Sebastian!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

There is an [extension for Unity](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Decorator-Unity-Container-Extension.aspx) that helps you in using it.

---

**Update**

[This solution](http://mrpmorris.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/decorating-unity-extension.html) is more explicit than the one by Jim Christopher.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. The solution your answer led to did not work with child containers and wasn't 100% suitable due to the way you had to register stuff, but the code did lead me to my own solution.

I'll be happy to accept your answer if you edit it and include the link I put in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you look into the Policy Injection / Interception side of Unity. This allows you to do decoration in a very lightweight and decoupled manner. This will be the easiest way of doing this.

You would essentially have a call handler that is executed whenever the Execute method is called which does the logging to the DB and then calls the "real" class.

Look at the ICallHandler interface, HandlerAttribute and the Interception extension in general.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I went with. It needs a bit of debugging but seems to be working fine for my current needs.

http://mrpmorris.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/decorating-unity-extension.html